# Could not open the Database, database is not being created

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to create a Database from my code with the entityframework. The Database Server is a MS SQL 2012 BI on a Window Server 2012 Data Center.

I try to do this with the example from MSDN. My Configuration Looks like this:

```
  <defaultConnectionFactory
        type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, 
            EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=databaseserver;User Id=name;Password=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=True " />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
```

I am getting a SqlException with "Error at Login for User xy", "Could not open the Database". This is obvious, since I want the code to generate the database, if needed. (Example from MSDN can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/data/jj193542)

edit: to avoid confusion some Facts what I want to do:

- I have a MsSql Server Setup with one Sql User and nothing
- I have classes which I want to write to a database.
- I am trying to do this with the example posted above, but Connection and/or creation of DataBase/DataBase-tables Fails.

Comment: try replacing the User Id and Password directly into the config.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding a "Initial Catalog" component to your connection string

Comment: @Learner what do you mean with config?

Comment: @daz-fuller i thought there is no Need to specify a inital catalog since with code first Generation of  entity Framework, the database gets generated

Comment: <parameter value="Data Source=databaseserver;User Id=name;Password=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=True " /> in here.

Comment: @Learner but I'm sorry I don't get it

Comment: What i mean is, in the above mentioned line, replace name with your DB username like "User Id= Your Database Login Id"  and password with DB password like "Password=Your DB Password" and also try adding "Initial Catalog = Your Database Name"

Comment: @Learner Well, like I posted above. I put in there userId=MY User Name and Password=THE Pssword from the user. The user is a SQL user, and SQL auth is on. I do not know what I should put as value as Initial catalog. An empty database?

Comment: It will create a database, but you need to tell it what the database should be called.  Otherwise it will connect to your default database (which typically is master).  So if you want to create a database called "MyDB" then the connection string should contain "Initial Catalog=MyDB"

Comment: Well, you need to have some database somewhere in order to connect to it (no matter empty or with data).

Comment: The database should not exist before it's created the first time though.  Unless you instruct EF to drop and create the database every time.  Otherwise you will need to use something like Migrations to update your database.

Comment: @Learner I tried it. I does not Change anything.  The Connection String in the Constructor of the DbContext is this (Initial catalog is overriten)"Data Source=mydbserver;Initial Catalog=TestConsoleApplication.BloggingContext;User ID=myuser;Password='mypw';MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"

Comment: As I understand it, and as it is shown in the example. The database does not exist, before it is created from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it to work. It seems my current solution somehow rejects working with entity Framework. I tried creating a new solution and there it worked. I will try and find the error in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

add connection string to your config file

```
    <configuration>
    ...

      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DerivedClassNameFromDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\; Initial Catalog=DbName; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=Username; Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>

    ...
    </configuration>
```

Or set connection string with constructor in your derived class from DbContext like this:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        ...

        public EFDbContext()
        {
             Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
                @"Data Source=.\; Initial Catalog=DbName; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=Username; Password=pass";
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I mean, I do not have a database specified for this allread. If I create a blank database, this db is not accepted.